# Whether using large arrays such as reg[127:0] temp[0:999] could make chip size bigger?

Tags: verilog

I am new to Verilog & FPGA world. A question arose in my mind, using large arrays such as reg[127:0] temp[0:999] could make chip size bigger?

```
module Memory();

reg [127:0] temp[0:999];

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example given here, the synthesis tools would optimise the array as it isn't being accessed at all (in general anything that doesn't change; or doesn't influence an output, is optimised away), so this example would actually end up as an empty design.

But, if the array was accessed and written to, then it would end up using a significant amount of resources in the chip. If it was both read and written synchronously in a suitable pattern, then it would map to 128000 bits of block RAM, which would fit on most FPGAs bar the smallest. Alternatively, if it was read asynchronously, it might end up as distributed RAM, which would take up quite a bit more space. Finally if it didn't meet the rules to map to dedicated RAM resources, it would end up as 128000 flip-flops and a large number of LUTs, which would not fit on many FPGAs (and be very wasteful in any case).

Comment: The simple answer is: If you actually write to and access the array unlike this example, then yes, it will use resources on the FPGA. How significant that resource use is depends on the size of the FPGA and details of the design.